# Integrate CkEditor 5 for Asp.net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor

I want to integrate CKEditor 5 (Latest version) for Asp.net (C# & ASPX) Project. But NuGet package manager and other forums including Stackoverflow leads me to use CKEditor version 3.6.4. 
How can I user the latest version in Asp.net (C# & ASPX) Project?

Where can I get anything relevant on this?

-Thanks

Comment: You can directly goto download page and use its cdn.<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/12.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

Answer (score 6):

Example given on their website

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CKEditor 5 – Classic editor</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/12.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Classic editor</h1>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtarea" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
    <script>
        ClassicEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '#txtarea' ) )
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
            } );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is a ready to use example from their site - but its not working as it is on an asp.net page if you use asp.net controls

Comment: it will work , its not working for you because ASP.Net will be generating dynamic ids for server controls. use ClientIDMode property to static for your textbox and use that id then. it will surely work. and yes it is the same example from their website as i stated at the start of my answer.

Comment: I will check it - the only last question is if on the post back, the TextBox is updated automatically as it is (and get the final text on code behind) - I believe that yet... and make the textbox, multiline

Comment: i didn't understood your question.

Answer (score 0):

Following the example of @Gagan Deep you can copy the content there every time CKEditor5 changes.

See this example:

```
ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('#txtarea'), {
        })
        .then(editor => {                
            editor.model.document.on('change', () => {
                console.log('The Document has changed!');
                $("#txtarea").html(editor.getData());
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
```

this code make the magic

```
.then(editor => {                
            editor.model.document.on('change', () => {
                console.log('The Document has changed!');
                $("#txtarea").html(editor.getData());
            });
        })
```